# Preserve cursor position after setValue in Ace editor

Tags: ace-editor

I'm developing a real time editor with ace and call editor.setValue() when ever there is a change in the editor and the cursor positions itself at random positions below the text. What I want is pretty obvious, the cursor to position exactly where the text ends after the set value loads the new texts. Any ideas??

Answer (score 2):

that is not very simple at all, because if the text have changed the `same position` will not be the same anymore.

if you want to restore the same selection, you can use toJSON method

```
before = editor.selection.toJSON();
editor.setValue(editor.getValue() + "xxx")
editor.selection.fromJSON(before)
```

but that in addition to being wasteful for performance, will not work correctly in the case when lines are shifted e.g. `editor.setValue("xxx\n" + editor.getValue())`

In general it is a better to use session.insert/session.remove methods

```
editor.session.insert({row: 0, column: 0}, "xxx\n")
editor.session.remove({start: {row: 0, column: 1}, end: {row: 1, column: 1}})
```

Comment: Thanks. What exactly do these methods (session.insert/remove) do?